# In XPath 3.1's array:filter, can I specify a filtering function that takes more than one argument (i.e. a value to test the item *against*)?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to filter an array of maps based on a value for one of the keys. The problems seems to be that the second parameter of `array:filter()` is a function that accepts only a single item parameter: `array:filter($array as array(*), $function as function(item()*) as xs:boolean) as array(*)` according to the [XPath and XQuery Operators 3.1 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-array-filter).

But when I do `array:filter($routingTable, function ($i) {$i?input ne $wid})`, with `$wid` being defined somewhere before this call, this variable is not being passed into the function and the comparison misses the crucial entries. (Checking the value of `$wid` with debugging output right before the call to `array:filter` confirms it has the correct value. Checking `$i?input` inside the anonymous functions confirms this value, too. But checking `$wid` *inside* the anonymous function makes it appear it is empty.)

So I thought maybe I need to pass the value to compare against to the filtering function as a second parameter, but when I do `array:filter($routingTable, function ($i, $wid) {etc...` , I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. I assume this is due to the excess argument of the function. How should I go about this?

For what it's worth, my XQuery processor is eXist-db (6.1.0) and here is more complete code (the call that's at issue (I assume) is the second line of the last function):

```
(: for a sequence of nodes, I build maps and put them into an array. that is my routing table that is then posted :)
declare function my:createRoutes($wid as xs:string) {
    let $index := doc($config:index-root || "/" || $wid || ".xml")/my:index
    let $routingTable := array{fn:for-each($index//my:node, function($k) {my:buildRoutingInfoNode($wid, $k)} )}
    return my:postRoutingTable($routingTable)
};

(: helper function to create a map from a node :)
declare function my:buildRoutingInfoNode($wid as xs:string, $item as element(my:node)) {
    map { "input" : concat($wid, ":", $item/@citeID/string()), "outputs" : array { ( $item/@crumb/string(), 'yes' ) } }
};

(: here the routing table is posted. However, if the entries are already present in the "live" table, I need to clean them from there first :)
declare function my:postRoutingTable($routes as array(*)) as xs:integer {
    if (array:size($routes) = 0) then
        0
    else
        let $testmap := $routes?1 (: okay, that's a bit cheap: I just check the first of the new entries. :)
        let $src     := $testmap?input
        let $dest    := $testmap?outputs
        return if (not(my:isInRoutingTable($src, $dest))) then
            ... post via http request ...
        else (: At least one key is already present, need to clean routing table for $wid first :)
            let $wid := substring-before($src, ":")
            let $cleanStatus := my:cleanRoutingTable($wid)
            return if ($cleanStatus ge 0) then
                my:postRoutingTable($routes) (: retry ... :)
            else
                -1 (: cleaning failed ... :)
};

(: remove all entries about the $wid (so that I can add them again) :)
declare function my:cleanRoutingTable($wid as xs:string) as xs:integer {
    let $routingTable   := my:getRoutingTable()  (: get "live" table :)
    let $cleanedRT      := array:filter($routingTable, function ($i) { 
                               substring($i?input, 1, 5) ne $wid
                           }) (: remove all entries concerning the to-be-posted $wid :)
    let $deleteStatus   := my:deleteRoutingTable()  (: drop the complete live table :)
    return if (array:size($cleanedRT) > 0) then     (: if after removing entries, anything is left of the original "live" table, :)
        my:postRoutingTable($cleanedRT)             (: then re-post this "cleaned" table :)
    else -1
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it this looks like an eXist-db bug. The variable `$wid` is part of the closure of the anonymous function and its value should be accessible; your code looks fine -- though without a complete repro (source document and expected results) I haven't tested it elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! So I am at least on the right track and the approach is reasonable in general. I have tested another trimmed-down variant in eXist-db and there it was working, so maybe it's a problem with my data (structures) after all. Still investigating...

Comment: I am relying heavily on scoped variables being available in lambda functions in my XQuery code. This definitely works in eXist-db’s processor. I am not aware of any recent changes that could have affected that.

Comment: I've no inside knowledge of eXist-db and I'm not sure if they answer questions here. You could start by tagging the question to bring it to their attention. Perhaps it's because the variable is a function parameter? But that's a wild guess.

Comment: Yes, in fact it was working. The problem was rather with the `let $wid := substring-before($src, ":")` in `my:postRoutingTable` that would then be the second parameter in the anonymous function. I mistakenly thought if there is no ":" in the `$src` string, by `substring-before` I would get the full string, whereas instead I really got an empty string. Feels quite embarrassing now. I hope I will be able to return to @line-o's answer and understand it better, maybe I might need it some time. But this time, this answer was the appropriate one and I should have checked my code better...

Comment: ... and, hence, it's working also in eXist-db now.

Answer (score 1):

## Passing a second variable to a filter function

To dynamically filter a list of items, one often needs to pass a second, dynamic parameter.

The usual way of a lambda or anonymous function that reads a scoped variable would be:

```
let $upper-bound := 4 (: this might be read from user input :)
return filter(1 to 9, function ($item) {
  $item < $upper-bound
})
```

With a little meta programming and leveraging the argument placeholder `?` this can also be rewritten as

```
declare function local:filter ($item, $upper-bound) {
  $item < $upper-bound
};

let $upper-bound := 4
return filter(1 to 9, local:filter(?, $upper-bound))
```

`local:filter(?, $upper-bound)` will return a function with an arity of 1 which is exactly what `fn:filter` and `array:filter` expect.
Main benefit is that it allows to reuse filter functions (here `local:filter`).
This function can now also be defined in an imported module.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I must admit it sounds intriguing but I don't yet understand how the standalone argument placeholder `?` is working here (and I'm not familiar with the concept of meta programming). So I'll be reading up on this and hope to grasp it at some point. As I've written in a comment to the other answer, for now it's not needed but I'll surely benefit from understanding what you did there...